# transform xml to latex with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, latex

I want to transform a text heavy xml file with a lot of font characteristics (bold, italic, letterspaced, small caps) as well as paragraph formatting (centered and indented textblocks etc.). Theses characteristics are invoked by an element + attribute structure in the xml file like this: `<hi rendition = "k" Some text </hi>` . The attributes value marks the font or paragraph characteristic - in this case the "k" stands for "small-caps" and the result of the transformation in this case would be: `\textsc{Some text}`. Now the problem is that these font attributes are combined in a completely irregular manner with other font attributes and on top they occur often within the mentioned paragraph styles. For  example: a text passage in sans serif  could be at the same time italized and it could occur in a centered environment like this:   `<hi rendition="c"><hi rendition="aq"><hi rendition="i">Cod. Theod</hi>. VIII. 12—15.</hi></hi>`. In this case the LaTex result should look like this: `\begin{center}\textsf{\textit{Cod. Theod}. VIII. 12—15.}\end{center}`

To illustrate the complexity here some part of one of these xml files:

```
<div n="3">             <head>§. 142.<lb/>
<hi rendition="aq">V.</hi> <hi rendition="g">Schenkung. Einleitung</hi>.</head>             <lb/>
<p>Quellen:</p>             <lb/>
<list>               <item>                 <hi rendition="aq"><hi rendition="k">Paulus</hi> V. 11.</hi>               </item>               <lb/>
<item>                 <hi rendition="aq"><hi rendition="k">Fragm. Vaticana</hi> § 248—316.</hi>               </item>               <lb/>
<item>                 <hi rendition="aq"><hi rendition="g">Cod. Theod</hi>. VIII. 12—15.</hi>               </item>               <lb/>
<item>                 <hi rendition="aq"><hi rendition="i">Inst.</hi> II. 7.</hi>               </item>               <lb/>
<item>                 <hi rendition="aq"><hi rendition="k">Dig.</hi> XXXIX. 5, XXIV. 1.</hi>               </item>               <lb/>
<item>                 <hi rendition="aq"><hi rendition="k">Cod. Just.</hi> VIII. 54—56, V. 16.</hi>               </item>             </list>             <lb/>
<p>Schriftſteller:</p>             <lb/>
<list>               <item><hi rendition="aq"><hi rendition="k">Donellus</hi> Lib. 5 C.</hi> 2 § 10 (Begriff und Inſinuation).<lb/>
<hi rendition="aq">Lib. 14 C.</hi> 26—32 (Widerruf). <hi rendition="aq">Lib. 13 C.</hi> 22 § 7. 8<lb/>
(Verſprechen der Schenkung).</item>               <lb/>
<item>                 <hi rendition="aq"><hi rendition="k">Mühlenbruch</hi> § 440—445.</hi>               </item>               <lb/>
<item>F. W. L. <hi rendition="g">von Meyerfeld</hi> die Lehre von den Schen-<lb/>
kungen B. 1 Marburg 1835. B. 2 Abth. 1. 1837.</item>             </list>             <lb/>
<milestone unit="section" rendition="hr"/>             
<pb n="2" facs="#f0016"/>
<p>Die </p>             <lb/>
<p>Juſtinians Inſtitutionen ſetzen ſie unter die Erwer-<lb/>
bungsarten des Eigenthums <note place="foot" n="(a)"><hi rendition="aq">Inst. II.</hi> 7. Dieſelbe Stel-<lb/>
lung giebt ihr <hi rendition="k"><hi rendition="aq">Hofacker</hi></hi> § 987.</note>; offenbar einſeitig und<lb/>
<lb/>
-<lb/>
cher ſie allerdings als <hi rendition="aq">justa causa</hi> 
riſchen Verträge <note place="foot" n="(b)"><hi rendition="g">Thibaut</hi> § 559. <hi rendition="g">Heiſe</hi><lb/>
B. 3 § 207. <hi rendition="k"><hi rendition="aq">Mühlenbruch</hi></hi> § 440.<lb/>
<hi rendition="g">Mackeldey</hi> § 421.</note>; offenbar eben ſo einſeitig, da das<lb/>
<pb n="3" facs="#f0017"/>
läßt.</p>         </div>
```

**Now:**

```
<hi rendition="aq" = \textsf{
<hi rendition="i"  = \textit{
<hi rendition="b"  = \textbf{
<hi rendition="c"  = \begin{centered}
<hi rendition="g"  = \so{
```

to mention just a few examples. Now in order to achieve the transformation I first want to get rid of the attributes using `<xsl:element>`. The result can than easily be transformed by a quick search and replace script. The problem is however that I only get the innermost `<hi rendition=".."` node. Here is what I mean:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="hi/hi">
<xsl:element name="{@rendition}">
\<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

run on the aforementioned example leads  to the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<div n="3">             <head>§. 142.<lb/>
<hi rendition="aq">V.</hi> <hi rendition="g">Schenkung. Einleitung</hi>.</head>             <lb/>
<p>Quellen:</p>             <lb/>
<list>               <item>                 <hi rendition="aq"><k>Paulus</k> V. 11.</hi>               </item>               <lb/>
<item>                 <hi rendition="aq"><k>Fragm. Vaticana</k> § 248—316.</hi>               </item>               <lb/>
<item>                 <hi rendition="aq"><k>Cod. Theod</k>. VIII. 12—15.</hi>               </item>               <lb/>
<item>                 <hi rendition="aq"><k>Inst.</k> II. 7.</hi>               </item>               <lb/>
<item>                 <hi rendition="aq"><k>Dig.</k> XXXIX. 5, XXIV. 1.</hi>               </item>               <lb/>
<item>                 <hi rendition="aq"><k>Cod. Just.</k> VIII. 54—56, V. 16.</hi>
```

There are two problems here:

1. It is impossible to know the depths of these nested elements in advance. Here I just assumed two nested <hi - elements.
2. I want to transform all `<hi rendition="xy"Text</hi>` into `<xyText</xy>` in one go. Is there a general solution to this that works independently of any specific assumption of the originals xml structure?

Comment: I haven't studied your data structure in great detail, but I don't think you need to know the nesting level.  Each `rendition` type equates to an opening string and closing string in LaTex. So just write a template that matches each type and wraps its contents in the required strings, with an `<xsl:apply-templates/> in the middle.  Make sure you provide templates to handle all the possible tags in the input.

Comment: You are absolutely right! I felt the solution had to be complicated and failed to see that it is super obvious. I will post the answer soon myself.